# How to run Valgrind and other tools to check memory leaks in Visual studio code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, dangling-pointer

I have installed "Valgrind Task Integration" extension in Visual studio code and after restarting VS code and typed the following Valgrind command in terminal,
"valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out.txt .mem_leak_fix"
for fixing memory leak issue for my sample C test code shown below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* mptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* mptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *mptr = 10;
    *mptr1 = 20;
    printf("mptr: %d\n",*mptr);
    printf("mptr1: %d\n",*mptr1);
    free(mptr1);
    mptr1=NULL; 
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting "The term 'valgrind' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again".

I have searched long time to know how to perform memory leak checks in visual studio for long time.
Kindly let me know how to install memory leak debugger tools in Visual studio and perform memory leak operations. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Last time I checked, which incidentally was [a few minutes ago](https://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html), Valgrind didn't run on Windows.

Comment: As an alternative to `valgrind` you could compile with `-fsanitize=address -g -O0`

Comment: @Kz2023 They've mentioned to use Valgrid on Ubuntu but I am working on Windows Visual Studio

Comment: @CraigEstey can we I use it on Windows Visual Studio?

Comment: In VSCode, an extension normally just brings the integration of some tool into VSCode. It does not bring the tool itself. That means, you would need to install Valgrind before you can use it with some VSCode extension. Or as you try, without using the extension at all by running commands in the terminal window. Unfortunately, that won't work for Windows.

Comment: BTW: Initially you mention VSCode but in the last sentences you mention VS. These are very different products.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` et. al. comes from the given compiler. It is supported by at least `gcc` and `clang`. In order to compile with VS, you had to install a compiler separately and tell VS to use it. Once the code is compiled with it, it just does the checking automatically (.i.e. run the program normally (e.g.) `./myprogram` as there is no need to do: `valgrind ./myprogram`)

Answer (score 0):

Learn to run Valgrind in a terminal. It will be just *sooo* much easier to begin with as you will only be learning one thing - Valgrind, and not two things - Valgrind and VS code.

Next, start with the simplest options. You shouldn't be starting with `--verbose`. I only recommend `--track-origins=yes` *after* you have found errors.

Valgrind does not run natively on Windows. You will need to install one of the supported platforms, see https://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html. You may be able to use WSL2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install or use something like VirtualBox or VMware or similar.

Comment: You mean to run Valgrid in Visual Studio ?

Comment: No. A terminal emulator. Konsole, Gnome terminal, xterm or whatever you prefer. All of the IDEs that I’ve seen do a crap job of integrating Valgrind. Not only do you have to learn extra IDE stuff which has no direct bearing on your problem but you will lose out on a significant amount of advanced functionality.